# how to create mysql database backups by using a query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to create a backup using phpmyadmin and not the mysql console.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an **Export** option you can use to backup your database. When you do so, it will also create queries for you :)

See:

**[How to backup your Mysql database with phpMyAdmin](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php)**

Comment: what would I choose from the options in export

Comment: check on "data" as well as" structure".